# Is there any advantage in using std::optional to avoid default arguments in a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdoptional

I'm porting code to C++17, trying to use the new features while possible.  One thing I like is the idea to use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to return or not a value in a function that may fail in some conditions.

I was curious about the possible usages of this new feature, and I'm thinking in start to use it to replace optional arguments in functions, so:

```
void compute_something(int a, int b, const Object& c = Object(whatever)) {
   // ...
}
```

Becomes:

```
void compute_something(int a, int b, std::optional<Object> c) {
   auto tmp = c.value_or(Object(whatever));
   // ...
}
```

According to the official doc:

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be
>   allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic
>   memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an
>   object, not a pointer, even though the operator*() and operator->()
>   are defined.

So, every time we use a std::optional to pass arguments, it implies a creation of copies than can be a penalty performance if the object is big.

I love the idea, because it make the code simpler and easy to understand but, is there any advantage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to give a good generic answer without knowing what specifically your function is doing, but yes, there are clear advantages to using `optional`. In no particular order:

---

First, how do you *propagate* default arguments when wrapping functions? With standard language default arguments, you just have to know what all the defaults are:

```
int foo(int i = 4);
int bar(int i = /* foo's default that I have to know here */) { return foo(i); }
```

And now if I change `foo`'s default to `5`, I have to know to change `bar` - which typically they'll just end up out of sync. With `optional`, only the implementation of `foo` needs to know the default:

```
int foo(optional<int> );
int bar(optional<int> o) { return foo(o); }
```

So that's just not a problem.

---

Second, there's the case where you provide an argument or fallback to a default. But there's also a case where simply the absence of an argument also has semantic meaning. As in, use this argument if I give it to you, otherwise do nothing. With default arguments, this has to be expressed with a sentinel:

```
// you just have to know that -1 means no fd
int foo(int fd = -1);
```

But with `optional`, this is expressed clearly in the signature and the type - you don't have to know what the sentinel is:

```
int foo(std::optional<int> fd);
```

The lack of sentinel can have positive performance impact too for larger sized objects, since instead of having to construct one to have that sentinel value, you just use `nullopt`.

---

Third, if `optional` ever starts supporting references (and many 3rd party libraries do), `optional<T const&>` is a fantastic choice for a defaultible, non-modifiable argument. There really is no equivalent to default arguments.

Comment: Excellent post! Did learn something! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

A `std::optional` is not a drop-in replacement for a function parameter default:

```
void compute_something(int a, int b, const Object& c = Object(whatever))
```

This can be invoked a `compute_something(0, 0);`

```
void compute_something(int a, int b, std::optional<Object> c)
```

This cannot be compiled. `compute_something(0, 0);` won't compile. At the very least, you must do a `compute_something(0, 0, std::nullopt);`.

> So, every time we use a std::optional to pass arguments, it implies a
>   creation of copies than can be a penalty performance if the object is
>   big.

Correct. But note that a defaulted function argument also needs to be constructed.

But you can do a few tricks by combining `std::optional` with a [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
#include <optional>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class X {

public:
    X()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
    }

    X(const X &x)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    X &operator=(const X &)
    {
        std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl;
    }
};

void bar(std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const X>> arg)
{
    if (arg)
        arg->get().foo();
}

int main()
{
    X x;

    bar(std::nullopt);

    bar(x);
    return 0;
}
```

With gcc 7.2.1, the only output from that is:

```
Constructor
Foo
Destructor
```

This does add a bit of syntax, and may be cumbersome. But, some additional syntactic sugar can mitigate the extra fluff. For example:

```
if (arg)
{
    const X &x=arg->get();

    // Going forward, just use x, such as:

    x.foo();
}
```

Now, let's take one more step:

```
void bar(std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const X>> arg=std::nullopt)
```

With that, the two function calls can simply be:

```
bar();
bar(x);
```

You can have your cake, and eat it too. You don't have to explicitly supply a `std::nullopt`, courtesy of the default parameter value; you do not have to construct an entire defaulted object, and when passing an object explicitly it still gets passed by reference. You just have an overhead of `std::optional` itself which, on most C++ implementation, is just a few extra bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Values wrapped into `optional` and default function parameters are not alternatives. They can be used together to achieve results that can not be achived if one or another is used separately. For example:

```
// user may or may not supply an item value
// if item is not supplied then the stock item will be constructed
// user can not choose to supply an empty item
void foo(t_Item item = t_Item{42});

// user must supply an optional item value
// though he can choose to supply an empty item
void foo(optional<t_Item> item);

// user may or may not supply an optional item value
// but he can choose to supply an empty item as well
// if no optional item value is supplied then the stock item will be constructed
void foo(optional<t_Item> item = optional<t_Item>{t_Item{42}});
```